# Image Gallery w/ Light Box - Image Links Not Swapping with others correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to create an Ecommerce Item gallery. I'd like it to be able to show the image that's selected to appear within the lightbox. Everything is working fine, except when the user selects the second thumbnail it does not show in the lightbox. The lightbox only shows the first images href. It seems that the 'href' is not swapping correctly after you select another thumbnail. This is also happening with the caption being passed through the "alt" attribute.

Here is my code.

```
    $(function() {
    $(".image").click(function() {
       var image = $(this).attr("rel");
       $('#image img').fadeOut("slow", function(){
           $('#image a').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
           $('#image a').fadeIn('slow');
       });
       return false;
    });
});

var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>'); //Stores Jquery Handler within a Variable.
var $image = $("<img>"); 
var $caption = $("<p></p>");

// Add Image to overlay
$overlay.append($image);
// Add Caption
$overlay.append($caption);
// Add overlay
  $("body").append($overlay); 


// Capture the click event on a link to an image.
$("#image a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //Prevents the  browser from loading the link in a new page!
    var imageLocation = $(this).attr("href");
  // Update overlay with the image linked in the link.
    $image.attr("src", imageLocation);

  // Show the overlay.  
    //console.log(href);
    $overlay.show();


  // Get Childs Alt attribute and set caption. (Childs Image Alt Attribute)
  var captionText = $(this).children("img").attr("alt"); 
  $caption.text(captionText);
});

//3. When overlay is clicked

$overlay.click(function(){
//3.1 Hide the overlay  
$overlay.hide();


});
```

Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dshojaei/cgv1sg3x/8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
// variables from images to hold onto
var url = "http://www.myorderdesk.com/Providers/832880/Files/7/image_1.jpg";
var caption = "This is the first caption";

// initialize the overlay 
$("#overlay").html('<img src="' + url + '"/><br>' + caption);

$(function() {
    $(".galleryImage").click(function() {
        // save the url and caption when clicking on gallery image
        url = $(this).attr("rel");
        caption = $(this).attr("alt");

        $('#image img').fadeOut("slow", function(){
           $('#image a').html('<img src="' + url + '"/>');
           $('#image a').fadeIn('slow');
       });
       return false;
    });
});

// when the user clicks on the enlarged image
$("#image").click(function(event){

    $("#overlay").css("display", "block");
  // Update overlay with the image linked in the link.
    $("#overlay").html('<img src="' + url + '"/><br>' + caption);

});

//3. When overlay is clicked
$("#overlay").click(function(){
    //3.1 Hide the overlay  
    $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
});
```

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1pvxx94b/) might get you started.

I would suggest reading up on some getting started guides for jQuery, Javascript, and CSS.  I think where you went wrong was not understanding exactly how jQuery's selectors work.

Try to keep your CSS IDs and classes well named, too.  When they are all called `image` it can be difficult to decipher what is what.

Additionally, there are pre-built lightboxes built on jQuery that you can use that will behave more responsively and give you more features.  I would take a look at those for inspiration or production if this is for a client.

Comment: Thank You i will take a look at this. This is my first JQuery project, so i'm actually just creating it to learn how to write. This is just for fun, and it's being based on paid plugins.

Comment: Keep at it.  If my solution answered your question can you please mark it as such?